# Kivy pass variable to screen and change screen

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Edit: i was trying to make a minmal app as John Anderson from the first answer told me to do  to reproduce my problem but i wasn't able but i got another error how can i make my self.manager to work along on the screens?

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'
  File "C:\Users\rbert\Desktop\stackoverflow\dashboard.py", line 39, in update_post_screen
    self.manager.get_screen("Post_view").list = list([post_id, post_body])
  File "C:\Users\rbert\Desktop\stackoverflow\dashboard.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.update_post_screen(self.item['post_id'], self.item['post_body'])
  File "C:\Users\rbert\Desktop\stackoverflow\main.py", line 12, in build
    return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
  File "C:\Users\rbert\Desktop\stackoverflow\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    CyberXtremeApp().run()
```

well i've searched along stack overflow but i didnt get an answer for what i'm searching
i have screens in separated files and my ScreenManager was specified in the main.kv file and what i'm trying to do is change some values on other screen before enter but when i try to change values with self.app.manager.get_screen it says

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1071, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "Post_view".
```

my screen code is this one it's called dashboard.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, IconLeftWidget, OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import json
import requests



class Dashboard(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.sub_title = ""
        self.nombre = ""
        self.Bienvenido = ""
        self.scroll = ScrollView()
        self.posts = list(self.get_posts())
        self.sorted_posts = self.posts.reverse()
        self.list_view = MDList()
        for self.item in self.posts:
            if self.item["post_status"] == "3":
                print("post oculto")
            else:
                self.icons = IconLeftWidget(icon="music")
                print(self.item['post_id'] + ", " + self.item['post_body'])
                self.update_post_screen(self.item['post_id'], self.item['post_body'])
                self.items = OneLineIconListItem(text=self.item['post_title'], on_press=lambda x:self.update_post_screen(self.item['post_id'], self.item['post_body']))
                self.items.add_widget(self.icons)
                self.list_view.add_widget(self.items)

        self.scroll.add_widget(self.list_view)
        # End List

        self.add_widget(self.scroll)

    def update_post_screen(self, post_id, post_body):
        self.manager.get_screen("Post_view").list = list([post_id, post_body])
        self.manager.current = 'Post_view'
        return print("ok")

    
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.app.title = "Posts"
    

    def get_posts(self):

        url = "https://example/api/"

        payload = {}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        return json.loads(response.text)
```

my dashboard.kv file is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
<Dashboard>:

  FloatLayout:
    MDLabel:
      id: sub_title
      pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.02, "top": 1.03}
      size_hint: (.5, .2)
      theme_text_color: "Primary"
      font_style: "Caption"
      halign: "center"
      text: root.sub_title

    MDLabel:
      id: Bienvenido
      pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.20, "top": 1.03 }
      size_hint: (.3, .2)
      theme_text_color: "Primary"
      font_style: "Caption"
      halign: "center"
      text: root.Bienvenido

    MDLabel:
      id: nombre
      pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.28, "top": 1.03}
      size_hint: (.3, .2)
      theme_text_color: "Primary"
      font_style: "Caption"
      halign: "center"
      text: root.nombre
```

my main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from dashboard import Dashboard
from post_view import Post_view
    
class CyberXtremeApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "TestApp"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette == "Blue"
        
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        print(self.ids)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CyberXtremeApp().run()
```

how can i pass variables through screen and change to screen with the ScreenManager specified on the kv file?
please don't explain me how to pass variables through screen on the same file because i already tried it and works but when i try to do with separated files the error comes up

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to be sure without more of your code, but I would suggest changing:

```
    self.app.manager.get_screen("Post_view").list = list([post_id, post_body])
    self.parent.current = "Post_view"
```

to:

```
    self.manager.get_screen("Post_view").list = list([post_id, post_body])
    self.manager.current = "Post_view"
```

Note that when a `Screen` is added to a `ScreenManager`, that `ScreenManager` is assigned to the `manager` attribute of the `Screen`.

Comment: hello thanks for your help i tried that already but i get this error:
self.manager.get_screen("Post_view").list = list([post_id, post_body])
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'
when i call the function on the on_preess function in the OneLineIconListItem and when i call it with lambda it only get the first key value on my list and what i want is to get the key value on the Post_view screen acording to the for loop key and value

Comment: also which other part of my code you need? the main.py?

Comment: added it but it didn't got the problem i was getting it shows up another error thanks!